# Twig: head blocks control from different controllers

Tags: symfony, twig

I use symfony 2.0.9.
Code of base.html.twig:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>        
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endblock %}        
    {% block javascript %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidebar">{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}</div>
<div class="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>            
</body>
```

My Bundle have own layout.html.twig, which being extended by Controllers, for example PostController.php with action showAction.

Code of layout.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    ...something
{% endblock %}
{% block navigation %}
    ...list of menus
{% endblock %}
{% block sidebar %}
    {% render "DevMyBundle:Page:sidebar" %}
{% endblock %}
```

How can access to block 'javascript' in base.html.twig from sidebar.html.twig, which rendered by PageController like this in layout.html.twig: {% render "DevMyBundle:Page:sidebar" %} or How can i reorganize structure of my templating. 
What for?: There are more blocks in sidebar may be. Each block call its own js. How? Thanks for advance.

Update: please, guys, help. There should be a simple answer. I have read twig docs, but im newbe in it. If i post this question not correctly, ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to move the sidebar javascrpt to it's own template. 
Something like this in layout.html.twig

```
{% block sidebar %}
    {% render "ZaysoArbiterBundle:Test1\\Main:sidebar" %}
{% endblock %} 

{% block javascript %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script>Some layout javascript</script>
    {% render "ZaysoArbiterBundle:Test1\\Main:sidebarjs" %}
{% endblock javascript %}
```

Comment: no, that's no way for me, because sidebar.html.twig not extends layout.html.twig or base.html.twig.
Its called by {% render "DevMyBundle:Page:sidebar" %} in sidebar block and i cannot write in it {% extends '::layout/base.html.twig' %}

And yes, i want to load js last

Comment: Ok.  I see the problem now.  Never tried to direct the output of an embedded controller to multiple blocks before.  Don't really think it can be done.  But I posted a new solution.

Comment: Hm.. this looks like an solution. Thank U.

Comment: Still have to figure out how to render Main:alljs(Action) after it collected all possible scripts)