# Embedded controller views with assets

Tags: templates, symfony

I am currently working on a symfony2 application and am using embedded controllers. My embedded controllers are like widgets which should encapsulate its own set of functionality and can be embedded anywhere and still be expected to function.

I have a controller called users online. The view it generates is simple, just a list of online users. But, I would like to add some javascript to that view so that I can use ajax to retrieve information for a user that's clicked on.

The controller basically returns a view:

```
return $this->render('AppBundle:Users:usersOnline.html.twig', array('somedata' => $data);
```

Here's the view for that controller:

```
{% extends partial.html.twig" %}
{%  block content %}
 <ul>
   <li><a href="site.com/ajax/user/1">User 1</a></li> (this would all be generated using 'somedata')
   <li><a href="site.com/ajax/user/2">User 2</a></li>
   ....
 <ul>
{% endblock content %}
{%  block scripts %}
   ..some javascript for interacting with this widget
{% endblock %}
```

This is the partial that is extended from:

```
{%  block content %}
{% endblock content %}

{%  block scripts %}{% endblock %}
```

Here's the main page that embeds the controller:

```
{% "base.html.twig" %}
{% block title %}Main{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
 ..some markup here
 <div id="usersonline">
  {% render "AppBundle:Users:usersOnline" with {'max': 4} %}
 </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
  ..some javascript
{% endblock %}
```

This is the base that it extends:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - App</title>       
     ...Some stylesheets
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.5.0pr2/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
        {%  block scripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem I am facing now is including javascripts from the embedded controller. In my case, the view extends partial and is fully rendered as 1 unit before it is inserted into the main page. In this case, I can only put my javascript in the `content` block, which means I will have `<script>` tags within `<div>` tags. I would also prefer to have scripts at the end of the body for user interface performance.

How should I structure my templates (or is it even possible) so that I can render the appropriate pieces from an embedded controller's view into appropriate blocks in the template that embeds the controller? In my current template the YUI library would be loaded after the embedded controller's rendered HTML markup, so accessing using the YUI library within the embedded controller would be impossible.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9224347/1146363) though easier to read.  I don't think the results of an embedded controller can be divided between multiple blocks.  The returned result is just the rendered html and not a twig template.  I think you need two embedded controllers, one for content and one for javascript.  And in some cases, maybe even one for css.

Comment: Hm. Having 2 embedded controllers is less than idea, and not very elegant imo.

Comment: Well you don't actually need two controllers, just two calls to the same controller with an argument that specifies what you want i.e with { 'generate' : 'html' or 'js' or 'css' }.  And then adjust your template accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written an extension which is essentially a token parser to deal with this. The documentation for the token parser is very sparse and the code is also mostly uncommented, so it took a bit of fiddling around to get working.

I have structured the parser so that at the beginning, you would declare something (similiar to `{% use %}`):

```
{% myparser "AppBundle:Users:usersOnline" with {'max': 4} as xyz %}
```

Then blocks like `xyzcontent` would be avaliable and then you just render them in the appropriate places using {{ block('xyzcontent') }}. It works quite well. However the following does not work:

```
{% set max = 4 %}
{% myparser "AppBundle:Users:usersOnline" with {'max': max} as xyz %}
```

I could not find a way to evaluate an expression and get its value directly within the token parser. For the most part it works fine, except for this problem.

If someone has some idea as to how to get the value of a variable within the token parser, it would be great :)

Comment: I am desperately looking for a solution for a similar problem: in my case I am writing a 'widget' bundle which is able to embed multiple controllers (which means, including other templates), but I want to be able to 'register' the assets (js/css/less) to the right block ('stylesheets' / 'javascripts'). Anyway, could you please share your Twig extension code? It's quite difficult to write my own token parser (no experience with it). Thanks in advantage.

Answer (score 0):

After one day of looking for a satisfying solution, I finally choose for the following approach:

- Render a controller for your widget's functionality (like you are already doing);
- Render templates to embed your widget's assets (controllers are not needed and will waste your performance). Ignore include if the template doesn't exist.
- Use a consistent naming convention to make the widget functionality more dynamic.

Example for one widget:

```
{% "base.html.twig" %}
{% block title %}Main{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
 ..some markup here
 <div id="usersonline">
  {{ render(controller("AppBundle:Users:usersOnline", {'max': 4})) }}
 </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
  {{ include("AppBundle:Users:usersOnline_js.html.twig" ignore missing }}
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ include("AppBundle:Users:usersOnline_css.html.twig" ignore missing }}
{% endblock %}
```

(As you can see, I use the Symfony 2.2 way of including and embedding)

Or, a more dynamic way of widget rendering:

```
{% "base.html.twig" %}
{% block title %}Main{% endblock %}

{% block widgets %}
 ..some markup here
  {% for widget in widgets %}
    {{ render(controller(widget.controller ~ ':widget', widget.options)) }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
  {% for widget in widgets %}
    {{ include(widget.controller ~ ':widget_js.html.twig' ignore missing }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
  {% for widget in widgets %}
    {{ include(widget.controller ~ ':widget_css.html.twig' ignore missing }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**My conclusion**

Rendering multiple controllers in one page, while "merging" it's templates blocks, cannot be achieved out of the box in Symfony2. Symfony2 has always been focusing on one controller for each request, which explains why multiple controllers outputs are separated and hard to combine.

I think the Symfony CMF has (or will have) a proper solution for this, because this whole widget topic is more applied in dynamic content managed websites.

Anyway, I think my way of combining embedded controllers and included templates is the best approach for Symfony 2 so far.

The alternatives, in my opinion, do have to many disadvantages:

- Using multiple controllers: too heavy and not needed because assets won't need any controller.
- Loading the widgets assets directly in the page: hard to maintain when changing widgets / assets.